# javascript string parsing in iPhone browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

Does anyone know why this code will parse and evaluate to true when a match is found in all browsers that I've dealt with except for the iPhone version of safari?
It even works on the desktop safari while set to iPhone mode, but in actual iPhone a match is never found.

- images is an array of the image names (ex: image1.jpg)
- P is an image object thats being evaluated
- thisOne is a variable to store the index when a match is found

  ```
  for(var q=0;q < images.length;q++){
  if(images[q] == P.src.substring(42).replace("%20", " ")){
      thisOne = q;
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: i would make simple example codes that checks that substring() works as you think on iphone, and that replace works as you think.  I would also check that P.src is correct.

Comment: I tried that and was able to confirm that the substring() method is getting the portion that I want. I took the replace out and checked on an item that I know doesn't require the replace. I had no luck. The P is being passed from another function, that may play a role. I will check that out and let you know what I find.